Ios is not able to play the audio form cached location file path throws exception
For now in my controller i have wriiten logic that for android platform it cache audio and the play which works correctly and for ios it should play directly from url but i want to cache in ios also to reduce time + I also observed that the loading time is also very high caching the file and then playing it how can i reduce that too
Error

flutter: ^[[31mAudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
DeviceFileSource(path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/879CF527-F744-4A78-9781-C5C199C9D26B/Library/Caches/libCachedImageData/95a93610-726b-1024-be1f-bb3cc5bb43ef.x-hx-aac-adts, mimeType: null),
PlatformException(DarwinAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, AVPlayerItem.Status.failed on setSourceUrl: Unknown error, null)<…>

audio_player_controller.dart
  void playAudio(String url, bool newSession) async {
    state = true;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) { 
      //Takes a lot of loading time due to downloading the audio file caching it and sending back the url 
      final res = await _audioPlayerRepository.getAudio(url);
      res.fold(
          (error) => debugPrint(
              'Unable to get audio file from the cache storage. $error'),
          (audioFilePath) async {
        final res = await _audioPlayerRepository.playAudio(audioFilePath);
        res.fold(
          (error) => debugPrint(error.message),
          (success) {
            debugPrint('successfully played $url');
            newSession
                ? _ref
                    .read(audioSessiontimerProvider.notifier)
                    .startSessionTimer()
                : ();
          },
        );
      });
    } else { 
      //Platform is ios look for caching problem till then play audio 
      final res = await _audioPlayerRepository.playAudioFromUrl(url);
      res.fold(
        (error) => debugPrint(error.message),
        (success) {
          debugPrint('successfully played $url');
          newSession
              ? _ref
                  .read(audioSessiontimerProvider.notifier)
                  .startSessionTimer()
              : ();
        },
      );
    }
    state = false;
  }

audio_player_repository.dart
  FutureEither<String> getAudio(String url) async {
    try {
      FileInfo? fileInfo = await _defaultCacheManager.getFileFromCache(url);
      fileInfo ??= await DefaultCacheManager().downloadFile(url);
      return right(fileInfo.file.path);
    } catch (error) {
      return left(
        Failure(
          error.toString(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

default_cache_manager.dart
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';

/// The DefaultCacheManager that can be easily used directly. The code of
/// this implementation can be used as inspiration for more complex cache
/// managers.
class DefaultCacheManager extends CacheManager with ImageCacheManager {
  static const key = 'libCachedImageData';

  static final DefaultCacheManager _instance = DefaultCacheManager._();

  factory DefaultCacheManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  DefaultCacheManager._() : super(Config(key));
}

